# Can FireFox extension perfrom this task

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

Can FireFox extension read the user's web URL, and after the user hits enter it performs a task (e.g. checks a blacklist) before the HTTP request is performed? I've been looking at many extensions examples but I am not sure if such task is possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest

Comment: @Daniel Herr thanks. I need to listen to the request before it is sent but I am currently working on something started with SDK not the new webextension. Can you help?

Comment: If you need an Add-on SDK solution, why is this tagged both Add-on SDK **and** WebExtensions. Please remove one or the other, as you do not appear to want both/either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done, it sounds like to want to use the [tabs api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) to read the current url and the [webRequest onBeforeRequest api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) to block requests